# What does "trimmed" mean in SciPy statistical functions?

Tags: statistics, scipy

When I tried to find the needed function in SciPy's Statistical package, I found that some functions are indicated to be designed for "trimmed" results, such as trimmed variance, trimmed maximum, etc.: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#statistical-functions. Could you please tell me what "trimmed" here means? Is the "trimmed" results the same as normal results? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the docs that you've linked to, you'll see that the trimmed versions include `limits` and `inclusive` optional arguments, and are described, e.g. for [`tmean`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.tmean.html) as:

> This function finds the arithmetic mean of given values, ignoring
>   values outside the given `limits`.
>
> - limits : `None` or (lower limit, upper limit), optional
>
>   Values in the input array less than the lower limit or greater than
>     the upper limit    will be ignored. When limits is `None`, then all
>     values are used.    Either of the limit values in the tuple can also
>     be `None` representing    a half-open interval. The default value is
>     `None`.
> - inclusive : (bool, bool), optional
>
>   A tuple consisting of the (lower flag, upper flag).    These flags
>     determine whether values exactly equal to the lower or    upper limits
>     are included. The default value is `(True, True)`.

Comment: Thank you! So, in more pythonic term, "trimmed" just means "sliced", right?

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of trimming functions

**trimming based on value:**

Trim (remove) all observations that are outside an interval of lower and upper limits.
This checks each value whether it's in the interval, and keeps the value if it is.
example in scipy.stats `tmean`

**trimming based on fraction:**

Trim (remove) a fraction of observations from each tail after sorting the observations, for example drop 10% of the smallest and 10% of the largest values.
This just takes the center slice out of a sorted array.
example in scipy.stats `trim_mean`

Both kinds of trimming are used to get statistics that are robust to outliers.